# How to add more light to the 3D view

Tags: 3d-view, light

Is there some way to add more light to the 3D scene during modeling?

Not to the final render, but just make the object more visible.

I followed few tutorials and I do exact steps but somehow their model during modeling phase is with more light even if no light in the scene is present.

---

To better explain myself - I'd like to make modeled object (without material and other stuff) to be more lighten up

Here is how I see object during modeling:
[image]

Here is the same object but I moved my position in viewport:
[image]

[image]

During tutorial (space corridor from blender guru)
is his object far more visible during modeling from different angles.
For me is my object far more darker - as it is visible on picture 1.

Comment: Perhaps it might help if you add a screenshot showing what is different between your 3D view and in tutorials.

Comment: at first I would select all of your object in edit mode then hit *space* -> and enter flip normals. This is because the normals of your faces are inside out, it also makes the object look darker.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To me your object doesn't seem like in the tutorial just because your **Normals** are inverted, go to edit mode of your mesh and press <kbd>A</kbd> couple of times until all your mesh is selected then press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>N</kbd> To recalculate Normals.

*Also if this will still not be enough you might consider changing the Shading in the properties panel to metcap and setting it to a light color*

Answer (score 4):

I'm afraid there is no way to fully fix this issue, but you can help slightly.

In **file** > **User Preferences** > **System** under "*Solid OpenGL lights*" (1) you can see three sets of colours (2). 
[image: OpenGL lights]

Editing all of these to a full white, (Clicking on each then adjusting the colour to the brightest white.) will *help* your issue.

EDIT: After viewing your edited post, i can say this is what my answer does. But like i said only to a extent. But, i have noticed, if normal's are pointing inside of a object, it is darker, the dark side of your object is unusual.

Try selecting the darker side in edit view with faces selected, then hold down 'CTRL' and press 'N'  this recalculates the normals. Also another thing to try is checking them manually. To do this, press 'N' then while in edit mode scroll down until you see a section called normals. (1)
[image: Normals]

Then click on one of the three boxes, i prefer faces (2) for normal things, but sometimes it doesn't matter what you prefer.

Answer (score 3):

You may do this in the ***Material*** settings. Go to the *Settings* panel and decrease the viewport specular's ***Hardness*** value or increase the viewport color's value.
[image]

Answer (score 3):

**NEW ANSWER**

Looking at your current information, it looks like your real issue is that your normals are reversed. To fix this, <kbd>Tab</kbd> into edit mode, select everything and then press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>N</kbd>. That should fix it, but if it doesn't, press <kbd>W</kbd> and look for flip normals, and click on that.

ORIGINAL ANSWER

While I know this isn't directly what you want, but changing the background color, or even the entire Blender theme is a way to make your objects more visible.

If you make the background color darker, it will make your objects seem lighter in contrast (although it may make some of the darker elements fade out a bit).

Here's an example:

Normal

[image]

Darkened 3D view

[image]

As you can see, the extra contrast makes it seem brighter.

How do you change the background color?

[image]

You'll notice that I highlighted an entire section. This is because there are options for gradients.

For gradients to be used, the Use Gradient checkbox needs to be enabled. Then the color used for each end of it is the high or low color fields, each controlling their respective ends. For a solid colored background the High/Off color field is used.

To choose a new Blender theme, simply use the Presets dropdown to choose one.

Answer (score 2):

[image]

Set the lights to be visible in 3D View and NOT rendereable in the final render.
In the outliner window you will see an eye for view, arrow for selection, camera for render.

The camera should icon be clicked and set to dull gray so it is not used in final render.
In Blender Render your 3D View should be in Texture Mode.